# Make Io language works on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, iolanguage

In order to run following example, I install Io on my Ubuntu 14.04.
But many Addons donot work.

> Socket
>   Size
>   [URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25078127/io-language-exception-object-does-not-respond-to-url/25078526#25078526)   ...

I follow the [post](http://jetpackweb.com/blog/2011/02/05/installing-the-io-language-in-ubuntu/) to install Io on my Ubuntu 14.04.

Io example code from "Seven language in Seven Weeks":

```
futureResult := URL with("http://bing.com/") @fetch
writeln("Do something immediately while fetch goes on in background...")

writeln("This will block until the result is available.")

writeln("fetched ", futureResult size, " bytes")
```

Refs:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have followed [post:Io Language Addons (and making them work in Ubuntu)](http://jetpackweb.com/blog/2011/02/08/io-language-addons-and-making-them-work-in-ubuntu/) to fix addon issue of Io.

Running following command to fix most addon issues:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential cmake libreadline-dev libssl-dev libncurses5-dev libffi-dev zlib1g-dev libpcre3-dev libpng12-dev libjpeg62-dev python-dev libpng12-dev  libjpeg62-dev libmysqlclient-dev libmemcached-dev libtokyocabinet-dev libsqlite3-dev libdbi-dev libpq-dev libgmp3-dev libogg-dev libvorbis-dev libtaglib-cil-dev libtag1-dev libtheora-dev libsamplerate0-dev libloudmouth1-dev libsndfile1-dev libflac-dev libgl1-mesa-dev libglu1-mesa-dev freeglut3-dev libxmu-dev libxi-dev libxml2-dev libyajl-dev uuid-dev liblzo2-dev zlib1g-dev

sudo apt-get install libtiff4-dev libtiff5-dev
```

Restart Ubuntu.

Anyway, above example works.

```
$ io future.io
Do something immediately while fetch goes on in background...
This will block until the result is available.
fetched 80454 bytes
```

Comment: The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libtag1-dev : Depends: libtag1c2a (= 1.9.1-2) but 1.9.1-2.2~ppa~trusty is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

Answer (score 2):

This is what worked for me.

1. Grabbed the dependencies from @Amitabha's post:

   sudo apt-get install build-essential cmake libreadline-dev libssl-dev libncurses5-dev libffi-dev zlib1g-dev libpcre3-dev libpng12-dev libjpeg62-dev python-dev libpng12-dev  libjpeg62-dev libmysqlclient-dev libmemcached-dev libtokyocabinet-dev libsqlite3-dev libdbi-dev libpq-dev libgmp3-dev libogg-dev libvorbis-dev libtaglib-cil-dev libtag1-dev libtheora-dev libsamplerate0-dev libloudmouth1-dev libsndfile1-dev libflac-dev libgl1-mesa-dev libglu1-mesa-dev freeglut3-dev libxmu-dev libxi-dev libxml2-dev libyajl-dev uuid-dev liblzo2-dev zlib1g-dev

   sudo apt-get install libtiff4-dev libtiff5-dev
2. Downloaded .deb file from [io homepage](http://iolanguage.org/) or [iobin](http://iobin.suspended-chord.info/). Choose x86deb or x64deb according to your ubuntu installation.
3. Extract the zip file (`unzip <zipfile>`)
4. `sudo dpkg -i <file.deb>`
5. `sudo ldconfig`. ReadMe suggests this.
6. Run `io`

Good luck